# discord.js | Clear command broke when I added music commands

Tags: discord.js

I am coding a discord bot, but I added music commands to it and now the clear command doesn't work.

index.js:

```
  
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]});

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command)
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('This bot is online!');
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember =>{
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'member');

    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('641315807745277993').send(`Welcome <@${guildMember.user.id}> to our server! Make sure to check out the <#791405102396735528> text channel!`)
});

client.on('message', message =>{

    message.member.roles.cache.has
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'youtube'){
        client.commands.get('youtube').execute(message, args, Discord);
    } else if (command == 'command'){
        client.commands.get('command').execute(message, args, Discord);
    } else if (command == 'clear'){
        client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'kick'){
        client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'ban'){
        client.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command =='mute'){
        client.commands.get('mute').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command =='unmute'){
        client.commands.get('unmute').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command =='reactionrole'){
        client.commands.get('reactionrole').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    } else if (command =='play'){
        client.commands.get('play').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    } else if (command =='leave'){
        client.commands.get('leave').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    }
});

client.login('[BOT_TOKEN]');
```

clear.js:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    description: 'Clear messages!',
    async execute(message, args){
        if(!args[0]) return message.reply("Please enter the amount of messages that you want to clear!");
        if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("Please enter a real number!");
        
        if(args[0] > 100) return message.reply("You cannot delete more than 100 messages!");
        if(args[0] < 1) return message.reply("You must delete at least one message!");

        await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[0]}).then (messages =>{
            message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
        })
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong? I can't seem to find the problem in my code.
The music part of the bot works fine, and the other commands work fine too, but I added the music part and now clear does not work, it worked fine before I added the music commands.

Comment: I don't really understand this...
If you have a command handler that lets you make a command like what you have in the clear command, why are you making a message event instead of just making another command similar to the clear one?

Comment: Ironically, I don't understand what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out (facepalm) I forgot to code the leave command for the music bot and I had used the beginning of the clear command to make the `module.exports` part, so the `leave.js` file was named clear within the file.